# If $f$ is an integer coefficient polynomial and $n$ is square free, does $f(\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2})=f(\frac{1-\sqrt n}{2})$ imply that $f$ is an integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

My question:

> If $f$ is an integer coefficient polynomial and $n$ is a square free integer, does $f(\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2})=f(\frac{1-\sqrt n}{2})$ imply that $f$ is an integer?

Suppose $\sum_ia_i(\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2})^i=\sum_ia_i(\frac{1-\sqrt n}{2})^i$, where $a_i$ are integers. I wonder if we can conclude that $a_i=0$ except for $a_0$ from here.

Comment: For one $n$, or for all (square free) $n$?

Comment: @dxiv For one square free $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$f(x)
=(x-\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2})(x-\frac{1-\sqrt n}{2})
=x^2-x+\frac{1-n}{4}
$
then
$f(\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2})=f(\frac{1-\sqrt n}{2})
=0
$
and if
$n=4m+1$
then $f(x)$
has integer coefficients.

Comment: But Marty, he asked whether the polynomial had to be constant. Didn’t he?

Comment: So the answer is obviously no.