# Completing a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2}][x]$ to a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ ($n=4k+1$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2}][x]$ ($n=4k+1$). I wish to find to a polynomial $g$ in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}{2}][x]$ such that $fg\in \mathbb Z[x]$.

One possible approach is setting $g$ to be $f$ with all $\sqrt n$ in the coefficients replaced by $-\sqrt n$. I don't know how to prove that the resulting $fg\in \mathbb Z[x]$.

I think $n=4k+1$ may be a necessary hypothesis, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2774403/185631) for an example.

Comment: Yes, the good method is to multiply $f$ by its conjugate, as you do, and $n\equiv1\pmod4$ is essential here. And: this is a consequence of fundamental ideas of algebra: the coefficients are in $\Bbb Q$ certainly, and they are also in $\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}2]$, and therefore integral over $\Bbb Z$. Thus they are in $\Bbb Z$, since this is an integrally closed ring (UFD proves that, for instance).

Comment: @Lubin Sorry, but this is actually a step to prove that this ring is a integrally closed ring... how do we prove the coefficients of thr product are integers?

Comment: Well. Then you simply show that $\Bbb Q\cap\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}2]=\Bbb Z$. This is even easier than my fancy approach. It uses the special hypothesis on $n$ to show that $\frac{k+m\sqrt n}2$ is in your original coefficient ring if and only if $k\equiv m\pmod2$.

Comment: @Lubin Why are coefficients of $fg$ in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Well, of course you need $n$ to be a nonsquare integer (the whole problem goes away otherwise). Now you show that $\lambda+\mu\sqrt n\mapsto\lambda-\mu\sqrt n$, for rational numbers $\lambda$ and $\mu$, is an isomorphism (preserves addition and multiplication), and that this “conjugation” leaves a number of that form fixed if and only if $\mu=0$. This is the Galois Theory of quadratic extensions. And of course the coefficients of $fg$ are fixed in this way, so they are rational.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks! Concerning your second comment... $\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt n}2]$ is the ring of "polynomials in $\frac{1+\sqrt n}2$", right? Not just $a+b\frac{1+\sqrt n}2$ with $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: Same thing: all you need to do is check that the product of two such is again such. Requires $n\equiv1\pmod4$.